# Modal & Dropdown is not working after upgrading to Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have the below Modal & Dropdown in my WordPress which were working fine in `v4.0.0-alpha.6`:

**Modal**

```
 <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#navLinkSub" aria-
 haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#">
 Link</a>

 <div class="modal fade" id="navLinkSub" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-
 labelledby="navLinkSub" aria-hidden="true">
 ....
 ...
 ...
 </div>
```

**Dropdown**

```
<div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-light dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="navShare" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                share
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navShare">
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">facebook</button>
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">twitter</button>
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">instagram</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I haven't changed any code which was working fine with earlier version on Bootstrap, than upgrading bootstrap to `v4.0.0-beta`.

Below is the jQuery & Bootstrap JS files in order:

```
<script src="......../assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js?ver=3.2.1"></script>
<script src="......../assets/bs/js/bootstrap.min.js?ver=20170722"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The and modal dropdown code looks fine. Try re-arranging the scripts. Jquery, Popper.js then bootstrap.js. Also, any external scripts you have to link them after. Don't change that order it is essential for it to work.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pp9pdjtv/
*The scripts are in the external resources tab on the left of your screen.*

**EDIT:** Seems that your scripts are in order. There is a possibility that one or two of the scripts are older and that causes some sort of compatibility issue. So, if my first fix doesn't work for you just take the scripts from the src="" tag and save them to your directory by using the shortcut ctrl-s. Then link them in the order I stated previously and make sure you get the right name of the script.

Comment: Thanks. Was missing `popper.js`, which was not part of earlier bootstrap versions...